# Como puedo copiar el texo de un Entry en tkinter al porta papeles?

Tags: python, tkinter

#generar_contraseña devuelve un string
#Mi problema es que cuando le doy a copiar contraseña me tira un error diciendo que con es un Nonetype y no se me ocurre como solucionarlo

```
from generador_de_contraseña import generar_contraseña
from tkinter import *

def imprimir_contraseña():
#tengo que asignar la funcion a una variable para poder mostrarla
    a = generar_contraseña()
#Creo una variable de tipo cadena
    cadena = StringVar()
#Creo una variable  global para usarla desde otra funcion
    global con
#Le asigno un entry a la variable y en text le paso la variable de tipo cadena
    con = Entry(root,text=cadena).grid(column=2,row=1)
#Por ultimo le indico el valor que va a tener la variable de tipo cadena
    cadena.set(a)

def copiar_contraseña():
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(con.get())

root = Tk()
root.title("Generador de contraseñas")
root.geometry("500x300")
Label(root,text="GENERADOR DE CONTRASEÑAS\n\n").grid(padx=30,column=2,row=0)
Button(root,text="Generar contraseña",command=(imprimir_contraseña)).grid(padx=10,column=1, row=1)
Button(root,text="Copiar contraseña",command=(copiar_contraseña)).grid(column=3,row=1)
root.mainloop()
```